# Force read-only prompt to "no" in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that are being used by multiple users. I saved it as read-only recommend prompt pop-up.

However, when I to use another program to open this file ( to refresh database and save the file ) , I still have to select read-only to 'No' from the prompt pop-up everytime.

How could I temporary enable the read-only prompt pop-up ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if opening from excel ... this should do it

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open ("yourfile.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

if opening from elsewhere, perhaps you could just use a "stub" workbook or xla with the same 3 lines of code to get at yourfile.xlsm.  Hope that helps.